How can I represent quantum states $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ in $x$ and $y$ bases?
For example, two persons choose at random whether to measure their
particle in the $x$ or $y$ direction (basis). We first define $x$ and $y$ eigenstates:
$|+x\rangle  =\frac1{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle  + |1\rangle )$;
$|+y\rangle =\frac1{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle  + i|1\rangle )$;
$|−x\rangle  =\frac1{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle  − |1\rangle )$;
$|-y\rangle  =\frac1{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle − i|1\rangle )$.
How do we get this:
$|0\rangle  =\frac1{\sqrt2}(|+ x\rangle  + |− x\rangle )$;
$|1\rangle  =\frac1{\sqrt2}(|+ x\rangle  − |− x\rangle )$

You can prove that with direct calculation. Just add states $|+x\rangle$ and $|-x\rangle$ to get $|0\rangle$. Similartly for state $|1\rangle$.

If you want to get the coefficients of a vector $v$ in any orthonormal basis you can take the inner product of $v$ with each of the basis vectors.
In your example, if you want to get the representation of $|0\rangle$ in the basis $\{|+\rangle, |-\rangle\}$ you get:
$|0\rangle = |+x\rangle\langle +x|0\rangle + |-x\rangle\langle -x|0\rangle$,
where $\langle +x|0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\langle 0|+\langle 1|)|0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and similarly for $-x$ and $\pm y$.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
